# QLineEdit and findChild()

Tags: c++, qt, oop, parent-child, qlineedit

I am trying to set the text of a line edit that is found using findChild()

mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::setValue(QString line, QString value){
    QLineEdit * edit = centralWidget()->findChild<QLineEdit *>(line);
    edit.setText(value);
}
```

However, I get an error on `edit.setText(value);` saying left of .setText must be class/struct/union.

How do I properly set the text of the child name `line` to be `value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `->` operator as edit is a pointer:

```
edit->setText(value);
```